# How to register onClick event after statechange?

Tags: reactjs

I have a javascript-event from en external library like this:

```
this.flky.on('staticClick', (e) => { this.setState({mobileZoom: true})
```

When I click it, an image gets expanded:

```
 <img onClick={this.state.zoom && () => {this.setState({mobileZoom: false}}}
 style={...this.state.mobileZoom && {position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: 'auto', zIndex: 1070}}
 />
```

This works on desktop, but on mobil, the onClick-event of the full-screen image also get's triggered, causing the image to just flicker and then disapear again.

It works if I add a delay:

```
this.flky.on('staticClick', (e) => { 
    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({mobileZoom: true}) }, 100)
)
```

but I have no idea how long the click event lasts on different devices, so this is not a sustainable solution and bad practice. Is there a better way?

Comment: You mean, you want to fire `staticClick` event after setting`this.setState({mobileZoom: true}` ?

Comment: No, when I fire staticClick the img onClick event gets fired aswell.

Comment: Have you tried the e.stopPropagation() method?
And btw, if you are not using 'e' as an argument, you can define the function without it () => { /* body */ }

Comment: Could you share the complete code of the `render` method? From the shared code it is not obvious where `flky` is placed in the hierarchy with respect to the image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop bubbling `event` further

```
this.flky.on('staticClick', (e) => { 
    if (event.stopPropagation){ //checking browser support
       event.stopPropagation();
    }else{
      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    this.setState({mobileZoom: true});
)
```

As an example

```js
function inside(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('you clicked inside');
}

function outside(e){
  alert('you clicked ouside');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="outside(event)">
  Outside
  <div onclick="inside(event)">Inside</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have typo in the `onClick`:

```
 <img onClick={this.state.mobileZoom && () => {this.setState({mobileZoom: false}}}
 style={...this.state.mobileZoom && {position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: 'auto', zIndex: 1070}}
 />
```